# Convergence of Fourier Series

Tags: analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Is there an $f\in L^1(\mathbb{T})$ whose Fourier series converges a.e. on $\mathbb{T}$ but not a.e. to $f$?

Answer (score 8):

If the Fourier series of $f \in L^1(\mathbb T)$ converges to $g$ pointwise almost everywhere then it will converge in Cesàro mean as well to the same function. Furthermore the Cesàro mean of the Fourier series of $f$ will converge in $L^1(\mathbb T)$ to $f$.

**Claim:** $f$ and $g$ must coincide.

**Edit: There is an error in the below argument, I will fix it tomorrow. I'm too tired now.**

Let $f_n$ converge to $f$ in $L^1$ and let $f_n$ converge almost everywhere to $g$ where $g \neq f$ almost everywhere.

Let $\mu$ be the measure, note that

$$
\begin{align}
\mu \{|f_n - f| \geqslant \varepsilon \} &\leqslant \frac1{\varepsilon} \int_{\{|f_n - f| \geqslant \varepsilon\}} \varepsilon \, \textrm{d}\mu\\
&\leqslant \frac1{\varepsilon} \int |f_n - f| \, \textrm{d}\mu.\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
And the RHS goes to $0$ for all $\varepsilon > 0$. Now fix $\varepsilon > 0$ and consider
$$M := \{x : |f(x) - g(x)| \geqslant \varepsilon \}.$$
We will show that this is a null set. Suppose as for contradiction that $M$ has positive measure.
Furthermore, define
$$M_m := \{x : |f_n(x) - g(x)| \leqslant \varepsilon \text{ for all } n \geq m \}.$$
These are clearly measurable increasing sets in $m$. As we have that $f_n \to g$ almost everywhere.
So almost every $x$ in $M$ is contained in one of the $M_m$. Hence the union
$$\bigcup_{n = 1}^\infty M_n$$
is equal to $M$ except for maybe a null set. This means that
$$\mu \left( \bigcup_{n = 1}^\infty M_n \right ) > 0.$$
So there is at least one $M_m$ with positive measure. So we have $|f_n(x) - f(x)| > \epsilon$ for all $x$ in this $M_m$ and higher $M_m$. Thus the LHS of $(1)$ cannot go to $0$.

More cool things:

[Kolmogorov (1923) - Une série de Fourier-Lebesgue divergente presqne partout](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm4/fm4127.pdf) gives an example of a $L^1$ function that has an almost everywhere divergent Fourier series.

For $1 < p < \infty$ this will not be the case due to the [Carleson-Hunt theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carleson's_theorem).

[Pointwise but not uniform convergence of a Fourier series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/10846/pointwise-but-not-uniform-convergence-of-a-fourier-series/10871#10871) might also be of interest to you.

Comment: Your argument is correct, but as the Fourier series may not converge to $f$ in $L^1$, this doesn't seem to solve my problem.

Comment: @Acky Well it if converges, then so will its Cesaro mean to the same function. The Cesaro mean of the Fourier series will converge everywhere where $f$ is continuous to $f$. Now if $f$ is Riemann integrable then it is a.e. equal to a continuous function.