# Intervals where the function is similar to the Fourier series

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

$$f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{l l}
0,\quad x \in [-L,0[\\
1,\quad x \in [0,L]
\end{array}\right.$$

I need to know in which intervals the sum of the Fourier series is "equal to the function $f(x)$".

Please help and help me understand how to solve it because I have four exercises like this... Thanks

Comment: What convergence theorems for Fourier series do you know?

Comment: A [related problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/180624/convergence-of-sum-limits-n-1-infty-frac-1n1-sinnxn).

Comment: Note that, your function is piecewise smooth.

Comment: Yeah that I know. But what about $$x=0$$? Discontinuity? This function has the value $$\frac{1}{2}=\frac{f(0+)+f(0-)}{2}$$

Comment: Consider the convergence on the sub-intervals and at the point of discontinuity, the series coverges to $ \frac{f(x+)+f(x-)}{2} $. You can see this directly if you subs $x=0$ in the series which gives you the value $1/2$.

Comment: By the way, do not forget to up vote the answer if you benefited from it.

Comment: So I say since the function is piecewise smooth in the intervals $$]-\pi,0[$$ and $$]0,\pi[$$ , at this intervals the function converge to the Fourier series,  at 0, $$\pi$$ and $$-\pi$$ the funtion converge to 1/2. Is that it?

Comment: You say the series converges uniformly to $f(x)$ on these sub-intervals.

Comment: Without the 0, pi and -pi. Don't refer to this points?

Comment: These intervals $(-\pi,0)$ and $(0,\pi)$.

Comment: Note that the values of the series at $-\pi$ and $\pi$ are the same as at $0$ AND YOU KNOW WHY?

Comment: Yes I do :) lol

Comment: Solved thanks a lot:)