# About Uniform Convergence of Complex Power Series

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, uniform-convergence

If a complex power series $$f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty } a_n z^n $$ is uniformly convergent in any closed subset of the open disc $\mathrm{B} (0,R)$, and converges pointwise on $\partial\mathrm{B} $, is it uniformly convergent on $\overline{\mathrm{B} (0,R)} $?

I have tried to prove but have difficulties at some step, so I think of it as wrong. If it is wrong, are there some counterexamples?

Comment: The answer "must"  be no - I can't  imagine why this would be true. Not that I have a simple counterexample...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the boundary of the disc of convergence, the power series essentially reduces to a Fourier series. There are Fourier series that converge pointwise but not uniformly. You can find an example here: [Pointwise but not uniform convergence of a Fourier series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/10846/pointwise-but-not-uniform-convergence-of-a-fourier-series)

One of the comments there also references Zygmund (Trigonometric Series I, p. 300). Zygmund mentions a similar result on power series following from the Fourier series one.

Comment: That example  you cite is not "of power series type"; that is, not of the form $\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_ne^{int}$.

Comment: Zygmund rewrites $f_{n,N}$ (he says he is following Fejer's proof) as a pure cosine polynomial $\sum_{k=N-n}^{N+n} a_k \cos(kx)$, which you can then turn into $\sum a_k e^{ikx}$, which is of power series type.